# PHPunit test error

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I'm new to PHP/PHPunit, I need some help! 
I'm working on an OpenCart project, I'm using PHPunit for Unit test. The class I need to test ModelSaleCustomer(admin\model\sale\customer.php) extend Model class(system\engine\model.php). I get that error when I'm running unit test.

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z6drV.png)
This is class test I created:

```
require_once 'C:\xampp\htdocs\IDOtest\system\engine\model.php';
require_once 'C:\xampp\htdocs\IDOtest\admin\model\sale\customer.php';

class ModelSaleCustomerTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

    protected $object;

    protected function setUp() {


        $this->object = new ModelSaleCustomer();

    }
    protected function tearDown() {

    }

    public function testAddCustomer() {
        $expected = 3;
        $content=array ('customer_group_id'=>'1', 'firstname' =>'bnhung', 'lastname'=>'nguyen','email'=>'nhungbng@gmail.com','telephone'=>'012345670','fax'=>'123456','custom_field'=>'', 'newsletter'=>'','salt'=>'','password'=>'1234', 'status'=>'','approved'=>'','safe'=>'','date_added'=>'');
        $result = $model->addCustomer($content);
        //$actual=  $this->object->addCustomer($content);
        $this->assertEquals($expected,$actual);
```

This is Class Model

```
abstract class Model {
    protected $registry;

    public function __construct($registry) {
        $this->registry = $registry;
    }

    public function __get($key) {
        return $this->registry->get($key);
    }

    public function __set($key, $value) {
        $this->registry->set($key, $value);
    }
}
```

and this is class I need to test

```
class ModelSaleCustomer extends Model {
    public function addCustomer($data) {
        $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "customer SET customer_group_id = '" . (int)$data['customer_group_id'] . "', firstname = '" . $this->db->escape($data['firstname']) . "', lastname = '" . $this->db->escape($data['lastname']) . "', email = '" . $this->db->escape($data['email']) . "', telephone = '" . $this->db->escape($data['telephone']) . "', fax = '" . $this->db->escape($data['fax']) . "', custom_field = '" . $this->db->escape(isset($data['custom_field']) ? serialize($data['custom_field']) : '') . "', newsletter = '" . (int)$data['newsletter'] . "', salt = '" . $this->db->escape($salt = substr(md5(uniqid(rand(), true)), 0, 9)) . "', password = '" . $this->db->escape(sha1($salt . sha1($salt . sha1($data['password'])))) . "', status = '" . (int)$data['status'] . "', approved = '" . (int)$data['approved'] . "', safe = '" . (int)$data['safe'] . "', date_added = NOW()");

        $customer_id = $this->db->getLastId();

        if (isset($data['address'])) {
            foreach ($data['address'] as $address) {
                $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "address SET customer_id = '" . (int)$customer_id . "', firstname = '" . $this->db->escape($address['firstname']) . "', lastname = '" . $this->db->escape($address['lastname']) . "', company = '" . $this->db->escape($address['company']) . "', address_1 = '" . $this->db->escape($address['address_1']) . "', address_2 = '" . $this->db->escape($address['address_2']) . "', city = '" . $this->db->escape($address['city']) . "', postcode = '" . $this->db->escape($address['postcode']) . "', country_id = '" . (int)$address['country_id'] . "', zone_id = '" . (int)$address['zone_id'] . "', custom_field = '" . $this->db->escape(isset($address['custom_field']) ? serialize($address['custom_field']) : '') . "'");

                if (isset($address['default'])) {
                    $address_id = $this->db->getLastId();

                    $this->db->query("UPDATE " . DB_PREFIX . "customer SET address_id = '" . (int)$address_id . "' WHERE customer_id = '" . (int)$customer_id . "'");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried to pass a `$registry` parameter to the constructor of `ModelSaleCustomer` in your `setUp()` method? Like this: `new ModelSaleCustomer($regsitry);` - with `$registry` filled with whatever object this class needs

Comment: I tried it before, but it doesn't work =(( I got new error: 
"Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\IDOtest\system\engine\model.php on line 10" and no tests executed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote working exapmle with some comments:

```
class ModelSaleCustomerTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    protected $object;

    protected function setUp()
    {
        define('DB_PREFIX', '');
        $mockRegistry = $this->getMock('Registry', ['get']);
        $db           = $this->getMock('db', ['query', 'getLastId', 'escape']);

        // Stub our "$this->db"
        // 1. Db stub expects call of "query" method
        $db->expects($this->any())
           ->method('query')
           ->willReturn(true);

        // 2. Db stub expects call of "escape" method
        $db->expects($this->any())
           ->method('escape')
           ->willReturn('stub');

        // 3. Db stub expects call of "getLastId" method
        $db->expects($this->any())
           ->method('getLastId')
           ->willReturn(3);

        // Stub registry, which should contain $db and return it on "get" method call
        $mockRegistry->expects($this->any())
                     ->method('get')
                     ->willReturn($db);

        $this->object = new ModelSaleCustomer($mockRegistry);
    }

    public function testAddCustomer()
    {
        $content  = array(
            'customer_group_id' => '1',
            'firstname'         => 'bnhung',
            'lastname'          => 'nguyen',
            'email'             => 'nhungbng@gmail.com',
            'telephone'         => '012345670',
            'fax'               => '123456',
            'custom_field'      => '',
            'newsletter'        => '',
            'salt'              => '',
            'password'          => '1234',
            'status'            => '',
            'approved'          => '',
            'safe'              => '',
            'date_added'        => '',
        );
        $result = $this->object->addCustomer($content);
        // Next line commented, because "addCustomer" actually doesn't return anything
//        $this->assertEquals($expected, $actual);
    }
}
```

You can start from here.

P.S. Tested with PHPUnit 5.0.3

Comment: Hello! I got another problem! When I run test case, it's pass but test data not inserting into database?? ;___;

Answer (score 0):

**It should help you**: [About Mocking](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html).
I think you can mock a class Model to isolate it, or you can just like in your comment

> StoryTeller:
>
> said add a `new ModelSaleCustomer($regsitry);`